# how to make a suvat calculator calculate from missing values

Tags: python, typeerror, calculator

I'm trying to code a suvat calculator to use a specific equation if certain values are missing but I keep getting errors with strings when I input nothing and errors like (TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float') or (TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)
Here's the code

```
s= input('Please enter the displacement: ')
u= input('Please enter the Inital velocity: ')
v= input('Please enter the Final Velocity: ')
a= input('Please enter the acceleration: ')
t= input('Please enter the time taken: ')

if s == "" and a == "":
    answer = float(0.5 * (u + v) * t)
    print("Your answer is", answer)

#### FIX THIS ^^^^^^ THE OTHER ONE TOO

if v == "":
    answer = u + a * t
    print("Your answer is", answer)
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. You need to convert your variables to floats before you do any calculations with them

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your question shows your research effort. By default, the input value will be a string and you need to convert it into the float.

```
s= input('Please enter the displacement: ')
u= input('Please enter the Inital velocity: ')
v= input('Please enter the Final Velocity: ')
a= input('Please enter the acceleration: ')
t= input('Please enter the time taken: ')

if s == "" and a == "":
    answer = float(0.5 * (float(u) + float(v)) * float(t))
    print("Your answer is", answer)

#### FIX THIS ^^^^^^ THE OTHER ONE TOO

if v == "":
    answer = float(u) + float(a) * float(t)
    print("Your answer is", answer)
```